# Align Semantic UI text menu center

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm new to Semantic UI, and I'm trying to have some responsive text menu items on top of my page which are  aligned to center of the page always. [Here's the sample of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/maniramezan/yyrbae6b/).

```
<div class="ui text menu">
    <a class="blue item" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="blue item" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="blue item active" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

I have tried to use grid based layout and many other approaches that are suggested on the Net, but all of them are related to compact menus which doesn't work on text menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using following code snippet:

```
<div class="ui relaxed grid">
    <div class="five wide column"></div>
    <div class="six wide column">
        <div class="ui grid text menu">
            <div class="five wide column">
                <a class="yellow item" href="#">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="five wide column">
                <a class="yellow item" href="#">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="five wide column">
                <a class="yellow item active" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="five wide column"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/maniramezan/yyrbae6b/1/)

Basically, I created a grid wrapper over my menu and also wrap each menu item in a `div`. That gives flexibility on fixing right and left margins and also add some space if needed between each menu item.